# how to extend PATH in zc.recipe.cmmi

Tags: buildout

Installing NPM using zc.buildout I need to extend the PATH environment variable:

```
[npm]
recipe=zc.recipe.cmmi
url=https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tarball/v1.1.1
environment = PATH=$PATH:${nodejs:location}/bin

[nodejs]
recipe=zc.recipe.cmmi
url=http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
#prefix option is added by default
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Installing npm.
npm: Unpacking and configuring
npm: Updating environment: PATH=$PATH:/Users/toutpt/makina/rempeitec/cubes/parts/nodejs/bin
./configure: line 11: dirname: command not found
sh: make: command not found
npm: cmmi failed: /var/folders/n0/srl4c2h500zfvcny_r55t41h0000gr/T/tmpKpXrcPbuildout-npm
While:
  Installing npm.
```

If I set the path myself it works but it's not repetable. I have tried $$PATH, \$PATH without success.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, but in any case it's much more convenient to install node.js packages by using [gp.recipe.node](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gp.recipe.node)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minitage.recipe.cmmi`, which will support to add something to `$PATH`.

```
[npm]
recipe=minitage.recipe.cmmi
url=https://github.com/isaacs/npm/tarball/v1.1.1
path=${nodejs:location}/bin
```